# Multitenant directory design

Tags: okta

I would like to implement OKTA API to manage authentication & SSO in a multitenant environment.
Each user should be linked to a single tenant, and authentication policies should be configured per tenant. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Okta uses an artifact called "organizations" to manage multi-tenancy. Authentication policies and other administrative settings can be applied to an entire organization, to "groups" within organizations and/or to specific users within a group.

Users can be provisioned within a single organization or in multiple organizations.

More information about the Okta API is available here: http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html

Comment: Great, thanks! But I do not find the API documentation to create and configure new organization on the fly... is there such?

Comment: No, there's no Org API resource. There is a private API but you have to request access to this through support.